# OpenGL,SOIL: Can I load a small png file or any size I want?

Tags: opengl, 3d, soil

I'm learning OpenGL and I used SOIL lib to map a texture(PNG file) to a quad
(follow NeHe tutorials).NeHe used a image size 256x256. Can I use a smaller picture ?(any size or power of 2 size) ?
 my load texture function:

```
int LoadGLTextures()                                    
{


    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
        "NeHe.png",
       SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT |SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO 
        );

    if(texture[0] == 0)
        return false;

    //glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);


    return true;                                        // Return Success
}
```

Comment: "I cant load it to texture"...like someone bursts into the room and smacks your keyboard away when you try to?

Comment: Dear genpfault, please ask your question instead of sarcastically implying the lack of information, OP might be confused as to what you mean :) his native language might not be english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have Re size your picture with photoshop or same software and be aware that your picture size should be power of 2 and between 64 and 256.and there is no need to code for that, but the size of openGL screen that you want to use for loading the picture can be determined with coding;)